# FormGroup async problem Edge vs Chrome in Angular

Tags: html, angular, asynchronous, formgroups

I've created a FormGroup that partially needs to **disabled** depending wether a **checkbox** is checked or not.
This worked with my code, but after a while I noticed that it didn't worked on Microsoft Edge (Only tested with Chrome). It only reacts

I took a look at my code, seemed that I made a mistake and that the UI showing on Microsoft Edge is correct, but the one in Chrome not..

It seems to me like an asynchronous problem because if I set a `console.log()` after `this.checkinForm.controls['releaseDropdown'].enable()`, it logs nothing in Chrome after clicking the checkbox on the first time.
After reclicking it for the second time it enables, but then the checkbox is unchecked and it should be disabled..

Anyone that sees what I'm doing wrong?

**Stackblitz**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqsd3y

My code looks like this:

**TypeScript**

```
checkinForm: FormGroup;
...
ngOnInit(): void {
...
 this.checkinForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      isCheckedRelease: new FormControl(false),
      releaseDropdown: new FormControl({value: null, disabled: true}),
      newRelease: new FormControl({value: null, disabled: true}),
      description: new FormControl(null),
      isCheckedConfig: new FormControl(false)
    });
...
}

 onCheckboxReleaseClick(){
    if(this.checkinForm.controls['isCheckedRelease'].value === true){
      this.checkinForm.controls['releaseDropdown'].enable()
      this.checkinForm.controls['newRelease'].enable()
    }else{
      this.checkinForm.controls['releaseDropdown'].disable()
      this.checkinForm.controls['newRelease'].disable()
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="checkinForm">
    <div>
        <label>The default chosen release in the configuration is: &nbsp;</label>
        <label style="color: red;"> {{defaultBranch}}</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Create or select a release for {{name}} </label>
        <input class="my-checkbox" formControlName="isCheckedRelease" type="checkbox" (click)="onCheckboxReleaseClick()" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Select a release:</label>
        <select formControlName="releaseDropdown" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.releaseDropdown.errors }" style="width: 50%;">
            <option *ngFor="let b of branches">{{b}}</option>
        </select>
        <label>Or create a new release:</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="newRelease" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.newRelease.errors }" placeholder="Name of the new release..." style="width: 50%;">
        <label>Description for release:</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="description" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.description.errors }" placeholder="Enter description for this release..." style="width: 50%;">
    </div>
    <div class="my-2">
        <label>Check-in config folder for {{name}}</label>
        <input class="my-checkbox" formControlName="isCheckedConfig" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: Stackblitz has been added :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found following fix:

**From** `(click)`

```
<div>
    <label>Create or select a release for {{name}} </label>
    <input class="my-checkbox" formControlName="isCheckedRelease" type="checkbox" (click)="onCheckboxReleaseClick()" />
</div>
```

**To** `(change)`

```
<div>
    <label>Create or select a release for {{name}} </label>
    <input class="my-checkbox" formControlName="isCheckedRelease" type="checkbox" (change)="onCheckboxReleaseClick()" />
</div>
```